# Crawling a court website and downloading records

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, selenium

I am new to Python and I am using Python 3.8 and Selenium.
This is a follow up of [my previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/241940/201050). Since I received several useful suggestions I have re-written the following code.

The code works fine and is much better than previous version. But I wonder if I can convert my code to be Page Object based. Will this improve the speed or readability etc?
I tried to achieve this with classes. Except when creating directories and selecting particular districts or complexes. The rest of the functions inside those classes remain static.

I don't expect any one to rewrite the code for me, but an elaboration on approach, a pointer on how refactor or any other improvements would be appreciated.
**Note**: kindly ignore comments, `#`, they are not yet well formed.

```
import base64
from typing import List
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
import time
import os
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import cv2
from pytesseract import pytesseract
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException, ElementNotInteractableException
import logging

# set logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='/home/sangharshmanuski/EcourtsData/logging_files'
                             '/ecourts_log_file.log',
                    filemode='a',
                    level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
# constants
url = r'https://districts.ecourts.gov.in/'

options = FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--private-window")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
# base dir path for downloading files:
main_Directory = r'/path to the directory/downloads6'
combo_identifier = '#sateist'
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 180)
waitShort = WebDriverWait(driver, 3)


# FUNCTIONS

def get_states(driver) -> List[str]:
    """Get list of States/UT from combo box
    Return a list of strings
    """
    try:
        # wait for combo box to be ready

        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, combo_identifier)))

    except TimeoutException:
        logging.exception('list of states failed to load')

    states_combo = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(combo_identifier))

    # return list of non-empty values from combo box
    state_list = [o.get_attribute("value") for o in states_combo.options if o.get_attribute("value") != '']
    logging.info('state list ready')
    return state_list


def get_districts():
    """
    Get list of districts form options
    It returns two values.
    1 is name (text from the element) of the district
    2 is value (attribute value) of that district
    """
    try:
        # wait for page to open and banner of district court to appear.
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.region')))
    except TimeoutException:
        logging.exception('districts not loaded')

    states_combo = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(combo_identifier))
    # return list of non-empty values from combo box
    districts_names = [o.get_attribute(
        "text") for o in states_combo.options if o.get_attribute("value") != '']
    district_values = [o.get_attribute(
        "value") for o in states_combo.options if o.get_attribute("value") != '']
    for each_district, number in enumerate(districts_names, start=1):
        logging.info(f'all the districts are:')
        logging.info(f'[{number}]: {each_district}')
    logging.info(f'district list ready. total districts: {len(districts_names)}.')

    return districts_names, district_values


def single_district(dist_number, some_districts_names=None, some_districts_values=None):
    # returns single district name and value of the district
    name_dist = some_districts_names[dist_number]
    value_dist = some_districts_values[dist_number]
    district_option = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(combo_identifier))
    district_option.select_by_value(value_dist)
    logging.info(f'\n \n \n new district: {name_dist} selected. It\'s number: {dist_number}')
    return name_dist, value_dist


def match_heading(some_district_name=None):
    heading_dist = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.heading')
    heading_dist_lower = heading_dist.text.lower()
    some_district_name_lower = some_district_name.lower()
    while heading_dist_lower != some_district_name_lower:
        time.sleep(1)
        logging.info('waiting')
    else:
        logging.info(f'district: {some_district_name} '
                     f'page loaded fully. Selecting case status by act')
        return True


def case_status_by_act():
    wait.until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.accordion2:nth-child(2)'))).click()
    select_case_status_by_act = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR,
         'div.panel:nth-child(3) > ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(6) > a:nth-child(1)')))
    select_case_status_by_act.click()
    logging.info('Case status by act selected. new tab will open')
    return select_case_status_by_act


def court_complex_list():
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#court_complex_code')))
    complex_combo = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#court_complex_code'))
    # return list of non-empty values from combo box
    court_complex_names = [o.get_attribute("text")
                           for o in complex_combo.options if o.get_attribute("value") != '0']
    court_complex_values = [o.get_attribute("value")
                            for o in complex_combo.options if o.get_attribute("value") != '0']
    logging.info(f'number of court complexes available: {len(court_complex_names)}')
    return court_complex_names, court_complex_values


def single_court_complex(complex_number, value_complex_list=None, name_complex_list=None):
    # returns single court complex name and value of the same
    complex_combo = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#court_complex_code'))
    value_complex = value_complex_list[complex_number]
    name_complex = name_complex_list[complex_number]
    complex_combo.select_by_value(value_complex)
    logging.info(f'\n {name_complex} selected. checking for records')
    return name_complex


def select_act(some_name_complex=None):
    """Populates list of acts.
    if the list is empty it waits for a 1 sec and tries again
    after trying 10 times it closes the effort and returns"""
    acts = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#actcode'))
    act_list = acts.options
    second = 0
    while len(act_list) < 2:
        if second < 10:
            time.sleep(1)
            second += 1
            logging.info('waiting for act list to be ready...')
        else:
            logging.info(f"sorry no act in {some_name_complex}")
            return False
    else:
        logging.info(f'PoA selected')
        acts.select_by_value('33')
        return True


def accept_alert(tab=None):
    try:
        waitShort.until(EC.alert_is_present())
        driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
        driver.switch_to.window(tab)
        logging.info('alert accepted')
        return True
    except (NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
        logging.exception('no alert present')
        return False


def wait_msg():
    try:
        please_wait = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#waitmsg')
        if please_wait.is_displayed():
            logging.info('please wait')
            return True
        else:

            return False
    except NoSuchElementException:
        logging.exception('no wait msg was present')
        return False


def wait_msg_wait():
    # wait for wait msg to disappear only for 5 sec
    # in case of alert wait msg remains for ever so waiting only for 5 sec is imp
    sleep = 1
    while wait_msg():
        if sleep < 6:
            time.sleep(sleep)
            sleep += 1
            continue
        else:
            break
    logging.info('captcha result ready')
    return


def invalid_captcha():
    # if captcha is invalid it returns true.
    try:
        incorrect = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#errSpan > p:nth-child(1)').text
        in_valid_captcha = "Invalid Captcha"
        if incorrect == in_valid_captcha:
            logging.info(f'{incorrect}, try again')
            return True
        else:
            logging.info('captcha cracked correctly')
            return False
    except NoSuchElementException:
        logging.info('captcha cracked, but may be no records found...checking')
        return False


def no_record_found(courtcomplex=None):
    # checks if no record found message is displayed

    try:
        no_record = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#errSpan > p:nth-child(1)').text
        no_record_available = "Record Not Found"
        if no_record == no_record_available:
            logging.info(f'no record @ {courtcomplex} please go to next court complex')
            return True

    except NoSuchElementException:
        logging.info('captcha cracked, record available, download now')
        return False


def captcha_to_text():
    # captures the captcha image
    logging.info('working on captcha now...')
    elem = driver.find_element_by_id("captcha_image")
    loc = elem.location
    size = elem.size
    left = loc['x']
    top = loc['y']
    width = size['width']
    height = size['height']
    box = (int(left), int(top), int(left + width), int(top + height))
    screenshot = driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(screenshot)))
    area = img.crop(box)
    full_path = r'/home/sangharshmanuski/Documents/e_courts/captcha'
    area.save(os.path.join(full_path, 'file_trial.png'), 'PNG')
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(full_path, 'file_trial.png'), 0)
    ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(img, 111, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    cv2.imwrite(
        '/home/sangharshmanuski/Documents/e_courts/editC/oneDisNoLoop.png', thresh1)
    # know the text with pytesseract
    captcha_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(
        Image.open(
            '/home/sangharshmanuski/Documents/e_courts/editC/oneDisNoLoop.png'))
    logging.info(f'text of the captcha: {captcha_text}')
    return captcha_text


def submit_form():
    # "enters captcha text taken from crack_captcha(..) function"
    captcha = driver.find_element_by_id('captcha')
    captcha.send_keys(captcha_to_text())
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input.button:nth-child(1)').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    logging.info('form submitted')


def download(some_district=None, some_complex=None):
    logging.info(f'okay, downloading record for {some_complex} in {some_district}')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.someclass')))
    list_all_view = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
        'a.someclass')
    logging.info(f'total number of records: {len(list_all_view)}')
    record = 0
    for view in list_all_view:
        logging.info(f'downloading {list_all_view.index(view)} record')
        view.click()
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'back_top')))
        open_file = open(
            os.path.join(main_Directory, some_district,
                         some_complex, "file_" + str(record) + ".html"), "w")
        open_file.write(driver.page_source)
        open_file.close()
        back = driver.find_element_by_id('back_top')
        back.click()
        record += 1

    logging.info(f'{some_complex} in {some_district} downloaded')


def dist_dir(some_district_name=None):
    district_directory = os.path.join(
        main_Directory, some_district_name)  # create new
    if not os.path.exists(district_directory):  # if not directory exists, create one
        os.mkdir(district_directory)
        logging.info(f'directory for {some_district_name} created')
    else:
        logging.info(f'directory for {some_district_name} was already there')
        pass
    return district_directory


def court_complex_dir(district_directory=None, name_complex=None):
    # makes separate directory particular court complex
    court_complex_directory = os.path.join(
        main_Directory, district_directory, name_complex)  # create new
    if not os.path.exists(court_complex_directory):  # if not directory exists, create one
        os.mkdir(court_complex_directory)
        logging.info(f'directory for {name_complex} in '
                     f'{district_directory} created')
    else:
        logging.info(f'directory for {name_complex} in '
                     f'{district_directory} was already there')
        pass
    return court_complex_directory


# MAIN CODE

# load the main page
driver.get(url)
print('working in progress. see the log file')
# Step 1 - select a state from list of states
# fixed selection from list. As only Maharashtra is covered now.

state_option = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(combo_identifier))
state = state_option.select_by_value('maharashtra')
list_districts_names, list_districts_values = get_districts()
# Step 2 - district object created
for x in list_districts_names:
    logging.info(f'district loop started. iteration: '
                 f'{list_districts_names.index(x)}')
    # step 2.1- select single district
    this_district, this_value = single_district(list_districts_names.index(x),
                                                list_districts_names,
                                                list_districts_values)

    dist_dir(this_district)

    match_heading(this_district)
    # step 2.3.a create variable for window handle
    current = driver.window_handles[0]
    # step 2.4 - a. select case status by act and b. switch to new window
    case_status_by_act()
    wait.until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
    # define new tab by differentiating from current tab.
    newWindow = [window for window in driver.window_handles if window != current][0]
    # 2.4.a
    # switch to the new tab. ref:
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41571217
    # /python-3-5-selenium-how-to-handle-a-new-window-and-wait-until-it-is-fully-lo
    driver.switch_to.window(newWindow)
    # 2.4.b new object from Formfilling(districtCourt)
    this_name_complex_list, this_value_complex_list = court_complex_list()

    # 2.4.c loop over all complexes

    for i in this_name_complex_list:
        logging.info(f'\n iterating each complex. currently at no.: {this_name_complex_list.index(i)}')
        # 2.4.1.1 select court complex
        this_name_complex = single_court_complex(this_name_complex_list.index(i),
                                                 this_value_complex_list,
                                                 this_name_complex_list)
        # 2.4.1.2 select act. 
        # If the acts are not available go to the next court complex
        # or if option for particular act is not present go to next court complex
        if not select_act(this_name_complex):

            driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input.button:nth-child(2)').click()
            single_court_complex(this_name_complex_list.index(i),
                                 this_value_complex_list,
                                 this_name_complex_list)
            if not select_act(this_name_complex):
                continue
        while True:
            submit_form()

            if accept_alert(newWindow):
                driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#captcha_container_2 '
                                                    '> div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) '
                                                    '> span:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(7) '
                                                    '> img:nth-child(1)').click()
                time.sleep(1)
                logging.info('captcha image refreshed')
                continue

            if not invalid_captcha():

                break
            else:

                continue
        # 2.4.5 if no record found go the next court complex
        if no_record_found(this_name_complex):
            continue  # skip rest of the code and continue the for loop from start.
        else:
            # 2.4.6 make new directory
            court_complex_dir(this_district, this_name_complex)
            # 2.4.7 download all the records
            try:
                download(this_district, this_name_complex)
            except (TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException, ElementNotInteractableException):

                driver.refresh()
                logging.exception(f'exception was present. Recheck {this_name_complex} again.')
                logging.info(f'skipping {this_name_complex} for now')
                continue

    logging.info(f'all court complexes in {this_district} completed')
    print(f'all court complexes in {this_district} completed')
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(current)

logging.info('all districts in maharashtra completed')
# 2.4.8 close the form page
driver.close()

# 2.5 all districts completed print statement and go to state-option page.

driver.back()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

### Log paths

It is not a good idea to hard-code this:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='/home/sangharshmanuski/EcourtsData/logging_files'
                             '/ecourts_log_file.log',
```

Probably use `pathlib.Path.home()` to replace that hard-coded prefix. Also, the usual thing to do for posix filesystems like that is `~/.EcourtsData` - most home-local data directories are dotted.

### Capitalized constants

```
url = r'https://districts.ecourts.gov.in/'
```

should be

```
URL = r'https://districts.ecourts.gov.in/'
```

### Incomplete type hints

What is `driver`, here?

```
def get_states(driver) -> List[str]:
```

You have a type hint for the return value but not the parameter.

### Odd string format

This:

```
f'\n \n \n new district: {name_dist} selected. It\'s number: {dist_number}'
```

First of all, the spaces between the newlines should not be there. Second, you can avoid needing to escape that single quote by using double quotes for the string. Third, I don't think the single quote should be there at all; it looks like a grammar mistake.

### OCR on a captcha

This is a deeply bad idea. First, if someone has a captcha on their site, it means they specifically don't want you scraping it, so this entire program is likely in bad faith. Beyond that, it's fragile and unlikely to consistently work.

### Selenium

Selenium is a last resort when a website is doing something so horribly complicated in JS that the only way to interact with it is to fake mouse clicks. In this case, thankfully, your website really isn't that complicated. It copies the `value` attribute of that `option` to the URL. You should be hitting the website directly with Requests; this should get you started:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Iterable

from requests import Session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

BASE = 'https://districts.ecourts.gov.in/'
STATE = 'maharashtra'


def doc_for_path(sess: Session, path: str) -> BeautifulSoup:
    with sess.get(BASE + path) as resp:
        resp.raise_for_status()
        return BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')


@dataclass
class District:
    key: str
    name: str
    act_link: str = None

    def fill_act_link(self, sess: Session):
        doc = doc_for_path(sess, self.key)
        anchor = next(
            a
            for a in doc.select('div.panel a')
            if a.text == 'Act'
        )
        self.act_link = anchor['href']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


def get_districts(sess: Session) -> Iterable[District]:
    doc = doc_for_path(sess, STATE)
    return (
        District(opt['value'], opt.text)
        for opt in doc.select('#sateist > option')
        if opt['value']
    )


def main():
    with Session() as sess:
        districts = tuple(get_districts(sess))
        for i, district in enumerate(districts, 1):
            print(f'Getting act link for {district}, {i}/{len(districts)}...', end='\r')
            district.fill_act_link(sess)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Edited to show that requests should be used instead.

Comment: Good advice overall. The only point that I'd like to raise here is the usage of `sess` instead of the whole word: `session` or `session_` if it shadows any builtin that I'm unware of ^^

Comment: It doesn't shadow anything; it's just a short form. `session` would be fine.

Comment: Thank you very much @Reinderien . Agree with you on captcha. The "bs4" part is fantastic. But, little extra for me. Can't digest it, even after breaking my head at it for hours. I tried to understand what and how the code is working... decoded it to some extent but then, not sure how to use it finally....my head is blowing! :)

Answer (score 3):

In `captcha_to_text`:

```
full_path = r'/home/sangharshmanuski/Documents/e_courts/captcha'
```

Use a **[temp file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html)** instead, if it's going to be discarded anyway (unless you want to investigate failures later).

---

In that same procedure and in other parts of your code you have multiple references to `/home/sangharshmanuski`. Define a global variable instead.

But you have a global variable already: `main_Directory = r'/path to the directory/downloads6'`, which is completely different. You are mixing disparate paths so I would suggest more consistency here.

---

Function `get_states` does not seem to be used. I think you kept it as an example. Remove unused portions of the code, declutter as much as possible.

---

Some **logging** messages should be **debug** level I think. When the application is mature enough, you'll probably want less verbosity and decrease the reporting level. So for dumping variables or application state etc use `logging.debug` instead of `logging.info`.

Since you are now using the logging module and this is a good thing, you can add more traces to better follow execution of your program. I would perhaps add a `logger.debug` line in each function so that you can track progress of your code and you can also verify that functions are not called multiple times or out of loop. Tracing execution is important.

---

Some functions I still find a bit perplexing:
`wait_msg_wait`: instead of doing `time.sleep` in a loop why not use Selenium functions eg:
`WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#theselector')))` if you are waiting for an element to disappear. Since you are using Selenium you have a lot of choice between implicit and explicit wait functions.

Seems to me that `wait_msg_wait` and `wait_msg` can be combined into one single function.

---

Scope: `variable combo_identifier = '#sateist'` is defined on top of the code. But if it's used in only one function, move it to that function to keep scope as limited as possible and avoid distraction.

---

Some functions are little or not commented
Example: `dist_dir`, `download`

In `download`:

```
os.path.join(main_Directory, some_district,
    some_complex, "file_" + str(record) + ".html"), "w")
```

You can use an F-string to avoid concatenation.

---

Since the project is not easy breaking up the code in small functions makes it more manageable. But I think this approach could have been pushed further. The main section remains very procedural and not that easy to follow.
For example, if I pick on line at random:

```
match_heading(this_district)
```

It's not immediately clear what this line does. For an outsider, more detailed comments would be welcome.

I would now try to split the main section in small functions as well like:

- load_home_page()
- break_captcha()
- dismiss_alert()
- get_states()
- download_court_records()
- go_back()

etc. The idea is to clearly identify the tasks involved, and better separate them.

---

Since there is a lot of code you could create a module to keep your functions in a separate file, then you import the module. Thus your main routine will be small and more manageable.